# Where to access calculated motion data after calling pose.paths_calculate

Tags: python

After calling `bpy.ops.pose.paths_calculate(display_type= 'RANGE', range= 'SCENE', bake_location= 'TAILS')` where is the motion data stored?

It is not `context.active_object.motion_path`, that one is used when calling `bpy.ops.object.paths_calculate()`

*EDIT*:
I found `context.active_object.obj.pose.animation_visualization.motion_path`, but this doesn't contain any points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stored in the bone itself